# Codeigniter CLI access without arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to run specific job through CLI, but I can select only a file - **I can't put arguments in there.** Now, ho to make it work?

I've tried creating cli_job.php and running it through CLI, but it returns homepage:

```
<?php

/* make sure this isn't called from a web browser */
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('CLI-only access.');

/* set the controller/method path */
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '/controller/method';
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "domain.com";
$argv = array("index.php", "controller", "method");

/* call up the framework */
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/index.php');
```

Thank you

Comment: The latest version of CodeIgniter has CLI support built-in: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: Yes, but I'm not able to use arguments in the CLI.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Call a CLI script from a PHP file?

Comment: I'm running a cron on shared server. That allows me to select only a file - I can't put there arguments.

Comment: The script in the question is what I tried as a workaround.

Comment: So, the PHP file you show is being ran via CRON?  And you want that PHP file to run a CodeIgniter CLI script?  Is that correct?  Can you use a shell script instead of a PHP file in your CRON?

Comment: yes, that's correct. no, I can run only PHP files

Comment: Does the CLI script you want to run have any output?  Do you want to do something with it if it does?

Comment: I'd like to have an output, although it's not essential.

Comment: It's a CRON job, yes?  Where would the output go?

Comment: It will be send as an e-mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to specify $_SERVER['argv'] variable and fake web access by extending Input class.

```
<?php

/* make sure this isn't called from a web browser */
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('CLI-only access.');

$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "domain.com";
$_SERVER["argv"] = array("index.php", "controller", "module");

require("index.php");



class MY_Input extends CI_Input
{
    function is_cli_request()
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a CodeIgniter controller via CLI, you need to call it via the command line, not via `include`.

Try to set your CRON script to something like this:

```
<?php
// Set the options for the CLI script you want to call
$index = 'index.php';
$controller = 'controller';
$method = 'method';
$params = array();

// Execute the CLI script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$passedParams = implode(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', $params));
exec("php {$index} {$controller} {$method} {$passedParams}");
```

Check the docs for CodeIgniter's CLI here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

<sub>Note: This works with the latest CodeIgniter version (2.1.4), I'm not sure if it works with older versions.</sub>

---

UPDATE: I was looking through my old CodeIgniter project, and I found a file that may help.

```
<?php
   $_GET["/controller/method"] = null;
   require "index.php";
?>
```

I haven't tested this, but it may work.  I'm not sure on the documentation for this, or even who made this file, but it was in my project, so it might work.

---

If all else fails, you could always do this:

```
file_get_contents('http://yourwebsite.com/index.php/controller/method');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not allowed to use `exec()` on shared hosting :(

Comment: @PeterDraexDräxler: Darn :(

Comment: @PeterDraexDräxler: I added some updates to my answer, maybe that helps?

Comment: 2nd option doesn't work for me... 3rd - the reason I'm trying to use CLI is to avoid limitations of the web server

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest.  Though, I did find this: https://github.com/compwright/codeigniter-cli-bootstrap maybe it'll help.  You might not be able to directly use it, but maybe you can look at the php file to see how they do it.